# How to insert data into mySQL table with java

Tags: java, mysql

I have created a database with a table with some columns. The connection is made with Java code.

But I have some issue when I run the program and fill the textboxes with name, adress etc.

They don't appear in the table in the database. Can you help me with code to insert data in the tabel without writing them in the code itself?

Here is some code:

```
package hardwarestore;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;



/**
 *
 * @author babar_000
 */
public class DerbyConnectionFactory {

    private static final String URL = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/tabeller";
    private static final String Username = "babar";
    private static final String Password = "babar";

    public static Connection createConnection() throws SQLException {
        return DriverManager.getConnection(URL, Username, Password);
    } 
} 
public class Kunde {

    private String navn;
    private String efternavn;
    private String email; 
    private String adresse;
    private String telefonnr;
    private String kundeID;
    private String kode;

    public Kunde(String navn, String efternavn, String email, String adresse, String telfonnr, String kundeID, String kode)
    {
        this.navn = navn;
        this.efternavn = efternavn;
        this.email = email;
        this.adresse = adresse;
        this.telefonnr = telefonnr;
        this.kundeID = kundeID;
        this.kode = kode;
    } 

    /**
     * @return the navn
     */
    public String getNavn() {
        return navn;
```

Comment: Always share your code to help yourself.

Comment: Intriguing - you are using an Apache Derby database URL and expecting inserts to happen in MySQL?

Comment: Also you don't actually have any insert statements (unless you didn't post all the code). I suggest you read a JDBC tutorial.

Comment: I suggest you read an SQL tutorial on how to do basic DB operations (SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggesting you to watch jdbc connection videos on Youtube which would help you to grasp the technique easily.

Providing a small example :

```
cnnct = getConnection();
string preQueryStatement = "INSERT  INTO  table_name VALUES  ()";
pStmnt = cnnct.prepareStatement(preQueryStatement);
```